# Save JTextPane, and Open it Java

Tags: java, save, jfilechooser, jtextpane

I'm trying to save a file using JFileChooser, but I cant seem to get it to actually save. 
I've tried a couple of different methods, but I want the user to able to save on desired location.
When I hit the "Save" button it says that it's saved. But when I try to find the file, it does not exist.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, DocumentListener{
JMenuItem aapne;
JMenuItem lagre;
JMenuItem sok;
JMenuItem farge;
JMenuItem oversett;
JTextPane tekstomraadet;
JTextPane dir;
String fratekst;
String tiltekst;
String tekst;



DefaultListModel listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
JList liste = new JList(listmodel);
public GUI(){

    this.setSize(1000,500);
    this.setLayout(null);

    //Passord

    passord pass = new passord();
    pass.password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Skriv inn et passord");
    while(!(pass.password.equals("words"))){
        pass.password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Skriv inn passordet på nytt");
    }

    //Liste


    liste.setBounds(900,0,100,600);
    liste.setBackground(Color.pink);
    this.add(liste);

    liste.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    listmodel.addElement("Hvit");
    listmodel.addElement("Svart");



    //Tekst



    tekstomraadet = new JTextPane();
    dir = new JTextPane();
    tekstomraadet.setBounds(0, 0, 890, 600);
    tekstomraadet.setContentType("text/html");
    tekstomraadet.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    this.add(tekstomraadet);

    //MENY

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fil = new JMenu("Fil");

    aapne = new JMenuItem("Åpne");
    lagre = new JMenuItem("Lagre");
    sok = new JMenuItem("Søk");
    farge = new JMenuItem("Endre farge");
    oversett = new JMenuItem("Oversett");

    aapne.addActionListener(this);
    lagre.addActionListener(this);
    sok.addActionListener(this);
    farge.addActionListener(this);
    oversett.addActionListener(this);

    fil.add(aapne);
    fil.add(lagre);
    fil.add(sok);
    fil.add(farge);
    fil.add(oversett);

    menuBar.add(fil);

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    this.setVisible(true);

}
//OVERSETTING

public String oversett (String input){
    input = input.replace(" en ", " 1 ");
    input = input.replace(" to ", " 2 ");
    input = input.replace(" tre ", " 3 ");
    input = input.replace(" fire ", " 4 ");
    input = input.replace(" fem ", " 5 ");
    input = input.replace(" seks", " 6 ");
    input = input.replace(" syv ", " 7 ");
    input = input.replace(" åtte ", " 8 ");
    input = input.replace(" ni ", " 9 ");
    input = input.replace(" ti ", " 10 ");
    return input;


}
public String Ord (String Ordene, String teksten){
    teksten = teksten.replace(Ordene, "<font color=\"red\">"+Ordene+"</font>");
    return teksten;
}
public String Ord2 (String Ordene, String teksten){
    teksten = teksten.replace(Ordene, "<font color=\"WHITE\">"+Ordene+"</font>");
    return teksten;
}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource().equals(farge)){

        if(liste.getSelectedValue().equals("Hvit")){
            tekstomraadet.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else if(liste.getSelectedValue().equals("Svart")){
            tekstomraadet.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            String ord = tekstomraadet.getText();
            String gammeltekst = tekstomraadet.getText();
            String nytekst = Ord2(ord, gammeltekst);
            tekstomraadet.setText(nytekst);

        }
    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(lagre)){

        JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
        filechooser.setDialogTitle("Spesifiser en fil for lagring");
        int rVal = filechooser.showSaveDialog(GUI.this);
        if(rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File fileTosave = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Save as file: " +fileTosave.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("hehe");
                ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(aapne)){
        JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
        int rVal = c.showOpenDialog(GUI.this);
        if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            tekstomraadet.setText(c.getSelectedFile().getName());

        }

    }

    else if (e.getSource().equals(oversett)){

        fratekst = tekstomraadet.getText();
        tiltekst = this.oversett(fratekst);
        tekstomraadet.setText(tiltekst);



    }
    else if( e.getSource().equals(sok)){
        String ord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Hvilket ord søker du etter?");
        String gammeltekst = tekstomraadet.getText();
        String nytekst = Ord(ord, gammeltekst);
        tekstomraadet.setText(nytekst);


    }

}




@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

If I use a fixed save, it works. But that's just a to much work for opening one file.

Comment: 1) Don't use `nullLayout` screen should work in different resolution 2) Don't implement interface in top classes make it in new classes that could be inner classes
3) Follow java code conventions, methods starts with lower cases, classes starts with upper-cases both following a camel case style

Comment: Please, simplify the code and let us know that you've tried simple debugging techniques. Please review the [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section of the FAQ for hints.

Comment: Sorry about the code. This is my first question on here, and I will improve it next time! :) And thans nachokk for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("hehe");
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
```

You never write with any of your OutputStreams. You need to write to the OutputStream, then flush and then close it. I believe that closing it (which should be done in the finally block) will usually flush the OutputStream.

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("hehe");
ObjectOutputStream o = null;

try {
   o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
   while (objectsAreLeftToBeWritten) {
     // get next object and write with 
     // o.writeObject(nextObject);
   }
} catch(....) {
  // .... etc
} finally {
  // if o is not null, close it
}
```

Comment: Or use try-with-resources , what is the meaning of `objectAreLeft`?

Comment: @nachokk: he'll iterate through something to write all the objects out. While there are objects left to be written, get next object and write to stream.